# How to delete all buffers in shell mode quickly

Tags: ibuffer

Emacs 26.1

First I create several buffers in shell mode.

[image]

Then I open `ibuffer` (`C-x C-b`) and mark all shell buffers manually by pressing `D` to delete them.

It works, but it's very slow. Is there a quicker method for deleting all buffers in shell mode?

Comment: A more general (but similar) question was asked [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/59378/how-can-i-kill-buffers-based-on-mode) with a few answers.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly quicker way that still uses IBuffer, is (from IBuffer) to use `% m shell` to mark all of the buffers in shell mode, and then press `D` to delete then all in one go.  Depending on what other modes you've got open you might get away with using "sh" instead of shell.  I use variations on this quite a lot to kill the many Ag and Dired buffers that I seem to typically end up with.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into the customizable var `ibuffer-saved-filter-groups`, to sort your buffers into groupings based on mode (or any other criteria).  Then you can mark a group at once by marking its heading.
Right now, they're all in one group `[Default]`, but you could easily have `[Shells]`, etc.